# Issue with Camel and Jackson Dependency

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, apache-camel

I'm facing an issue with the latest version of Camel and a REST DSL route. The full code can be found and run from here: https://github.com/mikevoxcap/nvisia-catalog-camel-service. I'm getting an exception when I try to run the route, underlying cause below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.getType()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;
....
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:926)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.marshal(JacksonDataFormat.java:154)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MarshalProcessor.process(MarshalProcessor.java:69)
```

My question is, which version of Jackson should I be targeting to no longer receive this exception.

I'm bringing in the following dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring.boot.version>1.3.5.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <camel.version>2.17.1</camel.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-swagger-java</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```

After doing some searching on the exception I received, several people have run into this issue when it comes to version conflict. I noticed that the camel-jackson library is bringing in jackson-module-jaxb-annotations 2.7.2, but the remaining jackson libraries are at 2.6.6. I tried excluding jackson-module-jaxb-annotations 2.7.2 and then directly including 2.6.6, but that still resulted in the exception.

My route is relatively simple:

```
  // Definition of the get catalog item endpoint
  rest("/catalogItem").
        // This is a GET method call for getting a catalog item by ID.
  get("{id}").
        // Description of what this method does
        description("Retrieve a catalog item by ID").
        // Define the output type that will be returned from this method
        outType(CatalogItem.class)
        // Define where the message is routed to as a URI. Here we use a
        // Spring Bean and define the bean method to invoke. Note that Camel
        // has converted the ID placeholder from the URL into a header
        // entry.
        .to("bean:catalogService?method=getCatalogItem(${header.id})");
```

My object being used as the JSON type is also pretty simple:

```
public class CatalogItem {

   private int id;
   private double price;
   private String catalogItemType;
   private List<CatalogItemAttribute> attributes;

public class CatalogItemAttribute {

   private String attributeName;
   private String attributeValue;
```

Comment: This error `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` indicates that either you are using the wrong method name or you are using a version of your dependencies that no longer have this method implemented or yet you are using a library version that doesn't have it implemented.

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes and that is what my question is here. The Jackson annotations dependency is a higher version when the POM is resolved. I'm trying to determine if I should be excluding the core Jackson libraries and increasing the version to be 2.7.2 across the board, of if there needs to be a downgrade to a version below 2.6.6.

Comment: So I added exclusions for jackson-annotations, jackson-core and jackson-databind to the spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-actuator, camel-jackson and camel-swagger-java dependencies. Then I specifically defined the dependencies for those three libraries with 2.7.2 and the code now works. After some research, this looks to be an issue with Boot more so than Camel. Looks like 1.4 of Boot updates to 2.7 of Jackson, so I'll just have to give this as the answer for now.

Answer (score 5):

While I haven't found anything official from Camel, it looks like this will resolve itself once Spring Boot 1.4 is released as it will be move to support Jackson 2.7. In the meantime, I updated my dependencies as noted below. I added exclusions for the jackson-annotations, jackson-core and jackson-databind libraries to the spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-actuator, camel-jackson and camel-swagger-java dependencies. Then I specified the three jackson dependencies with 2.7.2.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-swagger-java</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```